# Smooth hiding or showing visual elements (expandable ListView)

Tags: listview, animation, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview

I have an expandable ListView (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG10QPrRC3w)). How to make the motion happen smoothly (when i set IsVisible property to true)? Is it possible using ListView or i should use combination of layouts (StackLayout, Grid and etc.) to reach smooth motion?

I understand i can use animation methods (for example LayoutTo()), but it needs a lot of code in my case.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've searched and never found a cleaner way to achieve this but using animation. You can implement the 'expand' and 'collapse' animation logic into a behavior or trigger.

Comment: Diego, could you give a simple example of using behavior or trigger?

Comment: I found another way, but still have a problem  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293999/animation-and-gridlength-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I didn't have time to post an example yet, but what you've implemented in the other question is a real alternative indeed. I have an example with this kind of approach in a deletion action in a listview.

Comment: [I've answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300555/8093394). Please, let me know if it fits for what you need. It's not using triggers or behavior - I'll try to post this approach here as an alternative - but it should work as well.