# Animation and GridLength in Xamarin forms

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, gridlength

I have class Model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
...
private GridLength detailsPanelHeight { get; set; }
public GridLength DetailsPanelHeight
{
    get { return detailsPanelHeight; }
    set
    {
        if (!GridLength.Equals(detailsPanelHeight, value))
        {
            detailsPanelHeight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DetailsPanelHeight");
        }
    }
}
...
```

part of XAML code:

`<RowDefinition Height="{Binding DetailsPanelHeight}" />`

code to do animation (changing row height smoothly):

```
var animate = new Animation(d => currentItem.DetailsPanelHeight = d, 0, 100);
animate.Commit(this, "ExpandAnimation", 50, 1000, Easing.SpringOut);
```

code to collapse the row:
`var animate = new Animation(d => currentItem.DetailsPanelHeight = d, 100, 0);
animate.Commit(this, "CollapseAnimation", 50, 1000, Easing.SpringOut);`

It works for the first time, but for the second time i get an error: "value is less than 0 or is not a number\nParameter name: value". I see `d` value is less than zero.

What can i do to fix this problem?

Comment: @Diego, it doesn't help. I use 0.001 instead 0: `var animate = new Animation(d => currentItem.DetailsPanelHeight = d, 100, 0.001);`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with conversion between double and GridLength. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this that worked perfectly for me. I hope it fits for you too.

This animation collapses the view cell while calling a command after a *delete* action invocation. Here's the code:

#### The tap event handler:

```
private async void RemoveButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.Invoke(() =>
        {
             if (RemoveCommand?.CanExecute(RemoveCommandParameter) ?? false)
                 RemoveCommand.Execute(RemoveCommandParameter);
        },
        AnimatedDestruction);
}
```

#### Animation method

```
private async void AnimatedDestruction()
{
    uint transitionTime = 300;
    decimal delayFactor = 1.2m;

    // Note: stackPanel is the viewCell's top-level container

    await Task.WhenAll(
        stackPanel.FadeTo(0, Convert.ToUInt32(transitionTime * delayFactor), Easing.CubicInOut),
        View.InterpolateValue(stackPanel.Height, 0, Transition, transitionTime, Easing.CubicInOut)
        );
}
```

#### Transition callback function

```
private void Transition(double value)
{
    const double minHeightValue = 0.001;

    value = value <= minHeightValue ? minHeightValue : value;

    Height = value;
    ForceUpdateSize();
}
```

#### The `InterpolateValue` function as an extension method (very reusable)

```
public static Task<bool> InterpolateValue(this View view, double initialValue, double endValue, Action<double> transformIteration, uint length, Easing easing)
{
    Task<bool> ret = new Task<bool>(() => false);

    if (!view.AnimationIsRunning(nameof(InterpolateValue)))
    {
        try
        {
            easing = easing ?? Easing.Linear;
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            view.Animate(nameof(InterpolateValue), ((_double) => initialValue - (initialValue * _double)), transformIteration, 16, length, easing, (v, c) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(c));
            ret = taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
        catch
        {
            // supress animation overlapping errors 
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I hope it works for you.